# MPAndroidChart - Change message "No chart data available"

Tags: mpandroidchart

Is there any way to change the message *"No chart data available"* when the chart is not populated?

Edit: **Found the answer**

```
chart.setNoDataText("Description that you want");
```

Comment: Author found the answer to the question.

Comment: why you dont paste it as answer ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

update answer

```
chart.setNoDataText("Description that you want");
```

Comment: that is my reference https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2039

Comment: I have seen above thread, setting both `mChart.setNoDataText("");` and         `mChart.setNoDataTextColor(R.color.white);` has no effect.

Comment: try call chart.invalidate();  after set text let me know if this help

Comment: this is not working - it seems as if this is only working after one has already set data once before

Comment: @luckyhandler it is working, but you need to set it before creating a chart. E.g. right after the activity/fragment view is created.

Answer (score 13):

If you also want to customize look & feel, you can do it through `Paint` object:

```
mChart.setNoDataText("Description that you want");
Paint p = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
p.setTextSize(...);
p.setColor(...);
p.setTypeface(...);
...
```

Answer (score 9):

The Correct answer is here:

```
 pie_chart.setNoDataText("No Data Available");
 val paint:Paint =  pie_chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO)
 paint.textSize = 40f
 pie_chart.invalidate()
```

You also set other properties like text color, text typeface etc

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firestore__eintraege__heute);

    mChart = findViewById(R.id.chartZuckerHeute);
    mChart.setNoDataText("PUT IT HERE ON TOP; WORKED FOR ME");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need put `pieChart.invalidate()` after `setNoDataText()`:

```
@Override
    public void setDataMessagePieChart() {
        pieChart.setNoDataText("... your message ...");
        pieChart.invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `setNoDataText` is not working, you have to set it (and after that run an `invalidate()`) when you are initializing the chart. Don't do it when you are right away to set the data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30491835)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit old thread, but I had the same issue so my solution was to set nodatatext immediately after the initialization of a chart:

```
PieChart pieChart = findViewById(R.id.chart) //in case of fragment view.findViewById(R.id.chart)
pieChart.setNoDataText("Loading");
```