# Remove "No chart data available" from MPAndroidChart and add my own message

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) Library for showing a Bar Chart. Empty view for Data Bar Chart is showing "No chart data available":

[image: a chart saying "no chart data avalable"]

Also I need to change this message. But it's not working for changing this I have used this code lines:

```
mChart.setNoDataText("No chart");
mChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
pieChart.setNoDataText();
```

use it and u will get your desired Text
also if you want some descriptive text then you can use

```
pieChart.setNoDataTextDescription();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make chart invisible until data is populated. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe explain how to do that?

Comment: @Vemonus: I am fetching chart data from server. So as long as data is not available I am keeping chart invisible. As soon as data is fetched I am making chart visible after setting data

Comment: @Vemonus `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. Charts are a subclass of the `View` class

Answer (score 1):

First you can use:

```
chart.setNoDataText("Your description");
```

Then, you can customize through `Paint` object:

```
mChart.setNoDataText("Description that you want");
Paint p = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
p.setTextSize(...);
p.setColor(...);
p.setTypeface(...);
```

Font: [MPAndroidChart - Change message "No chart data available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892275/mpandroidchart-change-message-no-chart-data-available)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added LineDataSet?

```
LineData xData = mChart.getData();
ILineDataSet x = xData.getDataSetByIndex(0);
x = createXSet();
xData.addDataSet(x);

xData.addEntry(new Entry(5f, 21, 0);

xData.notifyDataChanged();

mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(30);
mChart.moveViewToX(xData.getEntryCount());


private LineDataSet createXSet(boolean drawPoints) {

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "x");
    set.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    set.setLineWidth(2f);
    set.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setFillAlpha(65);
    set.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
    set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setValueTextSize(9f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    return set;
}
```